# Comprehensive treatment of Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I don't intend to buy many books. Therefore, I am asking for a book containing a comprehensive treatment of functional analysis.
Otherwise Kreyszig or Rudin.

Comment: Peter D Lax, "Functional Analysis"

Comment: Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications 
by Philippe G. Ciarlet